# How to create NOT qualifier in view

Tags: calendar, view

I have a calendar view that I want to display all items where:

Start Time = Greater than or equal to [Today]

-and-

End Time = NOT Greater than [Today]

Basically, I want to view all items scheduled for Today, when the items span multiple days.

Is there any way to do this with out of the box SP?

Comment: Did you try: Start Time = Greater than or equal to [Today] -and- End Time = Less than or equal to [Today]?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`Start Time = Greater than or equal to [Today]` and

`End Time = Less than or equal to [Today]`

Comment: That doesn't work, because if Start is 1/1/2016 and End is 1/5/2016 and Today is 1/3/2016, then the End Time is greater than Today, so the second filter would be false and filter out a valid item. It would work if I could switch it around to - and [Today] is less than or equal to End Time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a view to show all events scheduled for Today, when the items span multiple days, then I suggest you use an [algorithm to detect overlapping events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513932/algorithm-to-detect-overlapping-periods) with today inside your view.

So you would add a view with three filter columns in the AND:

```
End Time is greater than or equal to [Today] AND
Start Time is less than or equal to [Today] AND
Recurrence is equal to No
```

If you dont add the last bit, then you will get recurring events (like birthdays or holidays) showing up in your view, which I don't think you want.